# Dynamically add path in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to add new functionality, without refactoring the entire code. Actually the code calls `msg.typeOfMsg('msg')`, but I want to add validation when it comes `true` change all the `typeOfMsg` to a specific type:

```
def specialRule = true

def message = changeMessageType()

def changeMessageType() {
  def toInform = { def message -> thePath.toChange.inform(message) }
  return specialRule ? [reprove : toInform, approve : toInform] : thePath.toChange
}

println(message.reprove('Standart reprove message')
```

This is the solution I found, it works, but I have a lot of message types and custom message types, there's some way to dynamically change all calls to inform, without refactoring all the code to calls something like `message(typeOfMessage, message)`?

-----Edit-----

Here's a runnable version

```
def message = changeMessageType()

def changeMessageType() {
  def originalPath = new OriginalPath()
  def specialRule = true
  def toInform = { def message -> originalPath.inform(message) }
  return specialRule ? [reprove : toInform, approve : toInform] : originalPath
}

message.approve('Standart reprove message') 

class OriginalPath {
  def reprove(message) {
    println "Reprove: ${message}"
  }
  def approve(message) {
    println "Approve: ${message}"
  }
  def inform(message) {
    println "Inform: ${message}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you come up with an example we can run?